# EveryPlay Video Showing Lines after upload

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

I have noticed user posting videos of my game with lines see

https://everyplay.com/videos/6184981

https://everyplay.com/videos/6136545

https://everyplay.com/videos/6131112

What causes this as I can't seem to reproduce it on any of my devices?

Thanks
Brandon

Comment: Update: Everyplay does not work on ANY model of kindle. Any ideas on how to fix this, or should I just disable everyplay from all kindles.

Answer (score 1):

The quality and implementation details between different video codecs is HUGE on android, they seem to be from Amazon Kindle's. Instead of disabling support for the device, it can be most likely fixed on-the-fly without requiring an SDK upgrade.

We've seen thousands of different Android devices so far, so I'm usually favouring not disabling the device if it mostly seems to work.. when a problematic device seems popular enough, just need to find the device physically and add it to our array of test devices. :) or find a contact who's willing to test it with us

Comment: Can you tell which version or versions of kindle are causing it? Can you tell if others on the same device have had successful submissions.  I will be willing to help in any way I can, but I only have a 1st gen kindle and it is not supported because it is on an old version of android. Thanks for all your help and for any thing else you can find out.